# setting up char** argv in code

Tags: c++, visual-c++, argv

So I have a program called prog.exe that starts with

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
```

The parameters that I pass to it are

```
prog.exe news-rec
```

or 
    prog.exe news-rec -t -p

How could I configure the values of these parameters in code so that I dont have to run the program from command line.

For example for

```
prog.exe news-rec
```

I think argc = 1 but how will I configure argv what will it be? 
I tried doing

```
argv[0] = "news-rec";
```

but that doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `argv[0]` contains the name of the executable itself. Try

```
argc = 2;
argv[1] = "news-recc";
```

Comment: @AdamZedan If you provided **at least some context** about this mysterious "not working", it would be far easier for us to deduce what is wrong and consequentially help you.

Comment: argc will increment as the first count is for the exe name.

Comment: @AdamZedan Awesome. Also thanks for Abhineet. If this worked, I'd appreciate if you accepted my answer.

Comment: @H2CO3- We all are here to help. My Pleasure. :-)

Comment: @H2CO3 Doesn't the argv structure need to be initialized before attempting to manually populate it?

Comment: @MihaiTodor nope, why would it? Anyways, if even you're not sure in this, why do you immediately downvote?

Comment: @H2CO3 I did not downvote your answer :( and I don't know who did. I'm just curious how is argv initialized when a program is executed, since I don't expect it to automagically resize itself when you write argv[2] = "foo"; argv[3] = "bar"; and so on, when the program is executed without any arguments...

Comment: @MihaiTodor of course it's not automagically resized, however it needs to be declared in such a way that there's enough space for all the arguments, e. g. `char *argv[3]` for a two-parameter program.

Comment: @H2CO3 OK, fair enough, but if you use `int main(int argc, char **argv)`, then who gets to initialize it and how can you add more stuff in `argv`? I was always curious how this works...

Comment: @MihaiTodor the OS sets that up. And it can't really be extended.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to give the **prog.exe** in your command-line argument as the exe name is always the **argv[0]** i.e. the first argument. Other than that, you can store as many arguments in **argv** as you wish, ex::

```
argv[1] = "new-rec" ;
argv[2] = "-t" ;
argv[3] = "-p" ;
```

and so on...

Assuming from the tag, that you are working on Visual Studio, you can try::

**Project Tab-> Properties-> Configuration Properties-> Debugging and then enter in the Right Hand Side under (Command Arguments)**, the arguments you want to pass **excluding** the **prog.exe**. The **argc** will automatically take the count of number of arguments you have passed.