# Passing command-line arguments to my c++ program through the visual studio gui

Tags: visual-studio

I have just started using Visual Studio 2012, which I wish to use to write C++ code.

To get to know how the IDE works I have created a very simple 'add two numbers' program.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>

int add(int a , int b)
{
  return a+b;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

  int a = atoi(argv[1]);
  int b = atoi(argv[2]);
  std::cout << "The sum of the arguments is  " << add(a,b)      << std::endl;  
  return 0;
}
```

If I hard-code the values of 'a' and 'b' (ie no argv's require to be passed), then using  <kbd>F7</kbd>  to compile and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  <kbd>F5</kbd> to run the executable makes the program run perfectly.

But how do I pass the `argv`'s to the program if I want to specify them at run time?

According to the 2nd answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12915669/setting-up-char-argv-in-code/12915762#12915762) SO thread I have to use **Project Tab-> Properties-> Configuration Properties-> Debugging and then enter in the Right Hand Side under (Command Arguments),**

But this seems very inconvenient if I want to make several quick runs of the program and test out the executable for different 'argv's.

Answer (score 1):

You can try **CLI Args Made Easy** from http://n0n4m3.codingcorner.net/?p=214.
There are versions for VS2010 and VS2012.

1. You may need to rename the downloaded file from .zip to .vsix, eg: **CLIArgsMadeEasy2012.vsix**
2. Double-click to install it.
3. Run Visual Studio.
4. Show the toolbar by right-clicking the toolbar area, and click **CLIArgsMadeEasy**
5. The toolbar appears with one textbox for command line arguments (CLIArgs) and a combobox (Startup Project)
6. Enter the argument in CLIArgs and remember to press the **Enter** key, otherwise the arguments will not be saved.
7. Run your program.

Comment: I just want to add my emphasis to step #6: remember to hit **Enter**, otherwise it looks like your arguments are being used but they actually aren't. That bit me more than once, before I made it an automatic habit.

Comment: @Edward, oh yeah that behavior hits me big time too :)